# Do variables referred to without using the this keyword in a Javascript class refer to the global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, es6-class

I was trying to make a menu driven JS program in node using class. The code I first wrote was wrong semantically but it worked anyway.

```
const read = require('readline-sync')
let flag = 1

class operations {
    
    constructor(num1, num2) {
        this.num1 = num1
        this.num2 = num2
    }

    addition() {
        let sum = num1 + num2
        console.log(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + sum)
    }
    subtraction() {
        let diff = num1 - num2
        console.log(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + diff)
    }
    multiplication() {
        let prod = num1 * num2
        console.log(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + prod)
    }
    division() {
        let quotient = num1 / num2
        console.log(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + quotient)
    }

}

do {
    console.log("Enter two numbers ")
    num1 = read.questionInt()
    num2 = read.questionInt()
    let opvar = new operations(num1, num2)
    console.log("Enter your choice of operation\n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division")
    let choice = read.questionInt()
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            opvar.addition()
            break
        case 2:
            opvar.subtraction()
            break
        case 3:
            opvar.multiplication()
            break
        case 4:
            opvar.division()
            break
        default:
            console.log("Invalid Entry")
    }

    flag = read.questionInt("Press 1 to continue and 0 to exit ")
}
while (flag === 1)
```

But how did it work without me using the 'this' keyword inside class methods? So if I don't use 'this' keyword will the class/object methods access the global variable of the same name?
I am a beginner so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

Comment: If they havent been defined locally,ie inside the function, then yes they will be looked up the scope chain till it reaches the global scope. And you set global variables with your `num1 = read.questionInt()` lines in your `do...while` loop

Comment: When a function is invoked with the new keyword, then the function is a constructor function and returns a new instance. In these cases,  "this" refers to a newly created instance.

Comment: Please, please run your code in strict mode and then this `accidental` assignment to globals will be flagged as a programming error (which it should be) and then this kind of stuff won't accidentally happen.  A error will be reported and you will have to fix the code to be correct.  `strict` mode is your friend.

Comment: @peter But we can't use 'var', 'let' or 'const' inside a constructor or outside a method in javascript classes can we? But we can use those inside class methods. Its a bit strange

Comment: `num1 = read.questionInt()` <-- well you probably would get different results if you actually declared what `num1` is and `num2`

Comment: Inside of class methods or inside the constructor, `let` or `const` just create local variables that exist only within the scope of that method (when the method is called) and a new copy is created each time the method/constructor is called - no different than using `let` or `const` inside a regular function.  These are just regular `local variables` in Javascript.   Don't use `var` any more.  Instance variables can be assigned within the constructor or can use the class `field` [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It depends on the scope in which the class was created. If it's a child scope, JavaScript will look for variables inside that scope. If there isn't any variable with the specified name, it will seek in the parent scope, until the global scope is reached or the variable is found.

For example, below there's a class created in the global scope. `val`, inside the `print()` function, refers to the global variable `val`.

```js
const val = 1;

class Example {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
  
  print() {
    console.log(val);
  }
}

new Example(2).print();
```

Here it's different. As the `Example` class was created inside the `if` block scope, `val` refers to the `val` variable inside that scope. If there wasn't any variable with that name, the value from the one in global scope would be returned.

```js
const val = 1;

if (true) {
  const val = 3;
  
  class Example {
    constructor(val) {
      this.val = val;
    }

    print() {
      console.log(val);
    }
  }

  new Example(2).print();
}
```

Also, if the function which is printing `val` had a variable named `val` within its scope, that's the variable whose value would be printed.

It's important to remember that if a variable is created using `var`, it will not be contained inside block scopes (in if, switch conditions or for and while loops).